# how to test a thread using powermock?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, powermock

There's a piece of code im trying to test,

which goes something like this:

```
class Foo {
    //do some operations
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //some piece of code
        }
    }
}
```

So how do i test the code within the run function.
I am using powermock,

The thread is started in another class so i should not invoke it there right??

im still a beginner.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the Runnable's run() method will be invoked on the Event Dispatch Thread. Usually only GUI updates should be performed on this thread. Using mock objects to test the GUI is not a good idea.

Comment: If your code updates the GUI and you really want to test it, you should try jfcUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to test.

If you're testing the behavior of `Foo` - don't worry about the concurrency. Just make your calls to `Foo` and assert that the result obtained matches your expectations. Just [`org.junit.Assert`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) will be enough.

If you're testing what this `Runnable` will actually do, you need to **break dependencies first**. Now your class `Foo` depends on some `Runnable`, which is instantiated and called internally. Convert it to an argument of `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
  private Runnable runnable;
  public Foo(Runnable rnbl) {
    this.runnable = rnbl;
  }
  // somewhere later in the class
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this.runnable);
}
```

Now you can mock this Runnable with, say, [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) and test (in your unit test):

```
Runnable mock = Mockito.mock(Runnable.class);
Foo foo = new Foo(mock);
foo.doSomething();
Mockito.verify(mock).run(); // verify that it was called
```

This is how you turn your multi-thread application into single-thread for testing only.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand the main problem is asynchrony. Test checks a result before we'll get result from invokeLater() block. So we need to wait until EDT run our code and after that check. We can do it via invokeAndWait method with empty runnable block. Example Foo class:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Foo {

    private String myLine;

    public void executeInEDT(final String line) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myLine = line;
            }
        });
    }

    public String getLine() {
        return myLine;
    }
}
```

and test method:

```
@Test
public void testInvokeLater() throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
    String testLine = "Test line";
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.executeInEDT(testLine);
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Just for sync
        }
    });
    assertEquals(testLine, foo.getLine());
    // And more asserts
}
```

**UPD**: Found some more information in [Netbeans test patterns](https://openide.netbeans.org/tutorial/test-patterns.html):

> As the queue of runnables is FIFO, the runnable is scheduled at the
>   end after all tasks posted by the application and when it is finally
>   executed one can be sure that all delayed tasks of the application in
>   the AWT event queue are over as well. See DataEditorSupportTest.java
>   for an example of a test that needs to wait while the application code
>   finishes some actions posted to the AWT event thread.